# Linux command to retrieve unique words and count along with punctuation marks

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
tr -c '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' < 4300-0.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

The following command retrieves unique words along with the count. I'd like to retrieve punctuation marks along with the unique word counts.

What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split your input with `tee` and extract punctuations and alnum separately.

```
echo "Helo, world!" |
{ 
    tee >(tr -c '[:alnum:]' '\n' >&3) |
    tr -c '[:punct:]' '\n'
} 3>&1 |
sed '/^$/d' |
sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

should output:

```
  1 world
  1 Helo
  1 !
  1 ,
```

A short `sed` script also seems to work:

```
echo "Helo, world!
OK!" |
sed '
    s/\([[:alnum:]]\+\)\([^[:alnum:]]\)/\1\n\2/g
    s/\([[:punct:]]\+\)\([^[:punct:]]\)/\1\n\2/g
    s/[^[:punct:][:alnum:]]/\n/g
' |
sed '/^$/d' |
sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

should output:

```
  2 !
  1 world
  1 OK
  1 Helo
  1 ,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[:punct:]` to retrieve the punctuation marks

And you can run:

```
tr -c '[:alnum:][:punct:]' '[\n*]' < 4300-0.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

it will print out the punctuation marks as well.

For example:
if you have in your txt file

```
aaa,
aaa
```

the output will be:

```
1 aaa
1 aaa,
```